# Xcode 8: UI tests can't find library being tested

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, xcode-ui-testing, dyld

When I created my iOS project, I opted not to include UI tests. Now, though, I tried to add them, but I get the following error when I try to execute them:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FrameworkBeingTested.framework/FrameworkBeingTested
Referenced from: <redacted>/TargetApplication.app/TargetApplication
Reason: image not found
```

I've confirmed that:

- UI tests are included in the `Test` scheme,
- the UI test target is set to use the correct Target Application (`TargetApplication`), and
- the UI test files are members of the `FrameworkBeingTestedUITests` target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer when I changed the UI test files' target membership to `FrameworkBeingTestedTests`, instead of `FrameworkBeingTestedUITests`:

[image: Error message]

Aha! The problem was that my `FrameworkBeingTested` had iOS 8.0 as its minimum target, but Apple's UI testing framework requires iOS 9.0 or newer. But instead of telling me that, the compiler told me that it couldn't load the tested library. I'll file a radar for this.

Hope this helps someone!